# Fluent NHibernate - Many To Many Relationship

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have **Product** and **Category** tables in database.

One product can have many categories. 
One category can have many products.

So, I have a third table as **ProductCategory**, which has ProductID and CategoryID.

In Fluent NHibernate, what should the mapping class look like?

For example, For **ProductMap** class is this correct:

```
HasMany(x => x.Categories).Table("tProductCategory").KeyColumn("CategoryId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108396?tab=newest#tab-top

See the question, see the responses. The problem is solved and you will learn why the inverse is important. Also using fluent you will need only to map the one side, not both.